# Container keeps restarting when trying to run consul agent as docker container

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, consul

I am trying to run consul agent as docker container. However, when I do volume mapping as shown below in the docker-compose.yml, the container always keeps restarting.

```
b1c4c6975b37        privatedockerhub/consul-agent:0.6.4   "/bin/consul agent -c"   3 seconds ago       Restarting (1) Less than a second
```

the docker-compose.yml looks as below

```
agent:
   hostname: abcd.com
   container_name: consul_agent_new
   image: privatedockerhub/consul-agent:0.6.4
   restart: always
   environment:
     - SERVICE_IGNORE=always
   volumes:
     - /etc/consul.d/client/config.json:/config/agent.json
   ports:
     - 8300:8300
     - 8301:8301
     - 8301:8301/udp
     - 8302:8302
     - 8302:8302/udp
     - 8400:8400
   command: -join 11.210.244.103 -join 11.210.244.104
```

the config.json looks as below:

```
{
        "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
        "data_dir": "/data",
        "leave_on_terminate": true,
        "dns_config": {
            "allow_stale": true,
            "max_stale": "1s",
            "service_ttl": {
              "*": "10s"
    }
        },
        "disable_update_check": true
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the logs? `docker-compose logs agent`

Comment: `/config/agent.json` you mean, its in `/data/config/agent.json`, right ? if yes, have you created /data/config folders in dockerfile ?

Comment: @BMitch the logs are showing the following output:  consul_agent | ==> Syslog setup failed: Unix syslog delivery error
consul_agent | ==> Syslog setup failed: Unix syslog delivery error
consul_agent | ==> Syslog setup failed: Unix syslog delivery error 
`

Answer (score 0):

This error appears where syslog daemon is not running. In our case we don't even need it because when we are running consul inside docker container, it will write logs to docker standard `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log` path not on syslog.

In my case I just turned it off inside config file `"enable_syslog": false` and it started working.